# Check and get the values of the objects

Tags: java

i want to get each instance for each object, i must check if one item is instance of the object, and then get the value, i have:

```
@Override
public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<TreeItem> event) {
 TreeItem item=event.getSelectedItem();

     if(firstGroup instanceOf TreeItem ) {
        Sun first=(Sun) item.getUserObject();
        ....;
    }
    else if(secondGroup instanceOf TreeItem) {
        Wall second=(Wall) item.getUserObject();
        ...;
    }
    else if(thirdGroup instanceOf TreeItem) {
        Sky third=(Sky) item.getUserObject();
        ...;
    }
```

but here work only the first if, and others don't. I need to get all values, can you please suggest me what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `else if` if you want all the conditions to be evaluated.

```
if(firstGroup instanceOf TreeItem ) {
    Sun first=(Sun) item.getUserObject();
    ....;
}
if(secondGroup instanceOf TreeItem) {
    Wall second=(Wall) item.getUserObject();
    ...;
}
if(thirdGroup instanceOf TreeItem) {
    Sky third=(Sky) item.getUserObject();
    ...;
}
```

`else if` would have made sense if all the conditions were checking the type of `firstGroup`, since if that was the case, only one of them could have been true for a given value of `firstGroup`.

After taking another look, it makes more sense to check the instance of the object you are actually casting, and in this case, `else if` makes sense :

```
if (item.getUserObject() instanceOf Sun) {
    Sun first=(Sun) item.getUserObject();
    ....;
} else if (item.getUserObject() instanceOf Wall) {
    Wall second=(Wall) item.getUserObject();
    ...;
} else  if (item.getUserObject() instanceOf Sky) {
    Sky third=(Sky) item.getUserObject();
    ...;
}
```

Comment: thank you, but it doesn't work :(. I need to get the values of the firstgroup if user clicks on it, and the values of the second objescts if user clicks on this object, and the values of the third object if user clicks on it

Comment: @Kaly What do you mean by "if user clicks on it"? Your question mentions nothing about any UI or clicking.

Comment: i have three objects and i need to get to know, to wich object belong each treeItem by onSelection() method in gwt. I need to comparison, if selected treeitem belong to one of these objects, then do something with each object

Comment: @Kaly What are `firstGroup`, `secondGroup`, `thirdGroup`? Where are they defined?

Comment: i can't understand by if clause, must i check wether one of each item belongs to treeItem, or each item belongs to one of the objects?

Comment: TreeItem firstGroup=new TreeItem(); TreeItem secondGroup=new TreeItem();TreeItem thirdGroup=new TreeItem();

Comment: @Kaly If that's the case, what the point of all those conditions that check if something is `instanceOf TreeItem`? You already know they are TreeItems.

Comment: i can't understand by if clause, must i check wether one of each item belongs to treeItem, or each item belongs to one of the objects? –

Comment: could you please tell me, how can i check if this treeitems instance of one of the objects?

Comment: @Kaly I edited my answer according to what seemed to make sense (based on the code you posted).